# How to take a reference to an element in array of structures [C# ]

Tags: c#, structure

Sorry for dump question, but I'm new in C# (moving from C++)...

I have a structure:

```
public struct A {
    int a,b,c,d;
}
```

Also I have an array of this structure instances

```
A[] a = new A[10];
```

So, I need to have a reference to one of the elements in my array:

```
A b = a[5];
b.x = 10;
```

But it looks like "b" isn't a reference, but copy of "a[5]". In other words, this code modifies "b", but doesn't change element with index 5 of array "a". So, the question is - How to take a reference to an element in array of structures?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Structs are value types (even in c++). Rewrite the above as a class and you should get the desired result.

Comment: in C++ I can write `A& b = a[5];` , but is it possible to do the same in C# without using classes?

Comment: @Tutankhamen You can pass value type elements of an array as `ref` to methods... But mutable `struct` are not generally advised and will lead to confusing behaviors. If you post your actual reason why you need that someone may suggest more C#-friendly approach.

Comment: I Just want to make local code shorter and easy to read. I have several multi dimension arrays of structures and I'd like to use short named local references to required element instead of using something like this `_animationList[_currentFrame][_boneNumber][idx]` ...

Comment: 2vishakvkt: The question was about structures, not classes.

Comment: even though syntactically you can do A& b = a[5] in c++, it is frowned upon for a number of reasons. In anycase, you can use pointers in c# to do this. Mark the method as 'unsafe', compile with '/unsafe' and then you can do A* b = a[5]; b-> x = 5;, and you are modifying the original struct

Comment: I can't use pointers in my project because this is a Unity project which have to be compiled/translated to Flash (AS3). I thought there should be a standard way to resolve my issue, but it looks like i was wrong. Thanks to all.